# How to get count of particular field using case in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, count

I'm trying to get count of a field based on some condition. But I cannot achieve the desired result yet.

**Table :: Quiz question :**

```
qq_id | qq_type | qq_title
----------------------------------------------------
1     | 1       | This is a multiple choice question
2     | 2       | This is a single choice question
3     | 4       | This is a descriptive type question
```

**Table :: Quiz question Details:**

```
qqd_id | qqd_question_id | qqd_option_text | qqd_option_is_answer
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1               | Yes             | 1
2      | 1               | No              | 2
3      | 1               | May Be          | 1
4      | 2               | Yes             | 1
5      | 2               | No              | 2
```

**Table :: Quiz participant answers:**

```
qa_id | qa_quiz_id| qa_participant_id | qa_question_id | qa_answer**
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1         | 3                 | 1              | 1
2     | 1         | 3                 | 1              | 3
3     | 1         | 3                 | 2              | 4
4     | 1         | 3                 | 3              | null
```

** The field qa_answer is the qqd_id of the quiz question details table.

The question (qq_id = 1) is a multiple choice question, hence there will be more than 1 answer. 
The question(qq_id = 2) will have only one answer, and question (qq_id = 3) will be a descriptive question.

The answers defined by admin are stored in question details table, we can see the qqd_question_id = 1 has 3 answers in which 2 of them are correct (qqd_id 1 & 3)

Calculating the correct answer count and total answered count, I'm getting total correct answers count as 3 (which is wrong and the expected is 2, because the question id (qq_id = 1 is a single question but has multiple answers)) and total answered count as 3 (which is correct).

I am using laravel 5.4 framework. I'm testing the query with the following query.

Note : for testing purpose I added additional field (qa_is_correct_answer) in the table (no joins with details table), please ignore that.

```
DB::table('quiz_answers AS QA')
            ->select(DB::Raw('QA.*, SUM(QA.qa_is_correct_answer = 1) AS correct, COUNT(DISTINCT QA.qa_question_id) AS total_answered'))
            ->where('QA.qa_quiz_id',$quizID)
            ->where('QA.qa_participant_id',$participantID)
            ->groupBy('QA.qa_quiz_id')          
            ->get();
```

**SQL Fiddle :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba1650/3

Comment: I don't follow your data entirely, but I will tell you that selecting `QA.*` while doing group by is invalid.

Comment: I can't see the desired result. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry i updated the question with link to the SQL fiddle

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MySQL allows it. Event if you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled, it works as long as all the other columns are uniquely determined by the grouping column, which will be true if you're grouping by the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar Just because it runs does not mean that the result set would be correct, assuming some of those columns are not functionally dependent on the group by column, nor that we should be encouraging such queries here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the group by column is the primary key, how can they not be functionally dependent on it? The fact that standard SQL doesn't allow that simplification seems to be a big misfeature, and MySQL has it right IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar If grouping by the primary key column then it is ANSI compliant, and should work across any database ideally.  In my experience, most of the time I see `SELECT *` in the context of a group by query on SO it is wrong.  Hence the gensis of my knee jerk comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to translate it into Laravel, but to keep from counting all the answers to a multiple-choice question as separate correct answers, you need to group them together in a subquery.

```
SELECT qa.*, SUM(qa.correct = 1) AS correct, COUNT(*) AS total_answered
FROM (
    SELECT qa.*, MIN(qa_is_correct_answer) AS correct
    FROM quiz_answers AS qa
    GROUP BY qa_quiz_id, qa_question_id
) AS qa
GROUP BY qa.qa_quiz_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba1650/7)

BTW, it's pretty weird to use `1` for correct and `2` for incorrect. For binary options, we usually use `0` and `1`, with `1` being the true value.

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what i was looking for !! . I know it's pretty weird to use values 1 & 2 for correct & incorrect respectively ;) . But i need to use this way